# Rails AJAX Like button Auto Change

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using the following code in my Rails application to generate a like/dislike button. I want the icon to change automatically without having to refresh the page. I've searched through the  questions on here but can't find anything that pertains to my situation. I'd greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

```
<div class="single-heart-this"> 
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if current_user.liked? @pride %>
      <%= link_to dislike_pride_path(@pride), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Like', toggle_href: like_pride_path(@pride), id: @pride.id } do %>
        <span class="heart-icon" style="background-position: 0px -290px;" data-id="<%= @pride.id %>"></span>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to like_pride_path(@pride), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Dislike', toggle_href: dislike_pride_path(@pride), id: @pride.id } do %>
        <span class="heart-icon" style="background-position: 0px -256px;" data-id="<%= @pride.id %>"></span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <span class="heart-no" data-id="<%= @pride.id %>"><%= @pride.get_likes.size %></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
  #config/routes.rb
  resources :pride

  #app/controllers/prides_controller.rb
  Class PrideController < ApplicationController
     def update 
        ... #-> logic here
        respond_to do |format|
           format.js #-> loads app/views/pride/update.js.erb
        end
     end
  end

  #app/views/pride/update.js.erb
  $(".single-heart-this").html("<%=j render partial: 'vote', locals: { pride: @pride } %>")

  #app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
  <div class="single-heart-this"> 
      <%= render partial: "vote", locals: { pride: @pride } %>
  </div>

  #app/views/controllers/_vote.html.erb
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to pride_path(@pride), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, id: @pride.iddo %>
        <% style = current_user.liked?(@pride)? "-290px" : "-256px"
        <span class="heart-icon" style="background-position: 0px <%= style %>;" data-id="<%= @pride.id %>"></span>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I Rich. Thank you for the response. I did try this approach but it appears I am still required to refresh the page instead if it happening automatically. Any thoughts?